# How to UPDATE a RowCount using multiple tables and INNER JOIN in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I don't know if this can be done is a single statement, but I thought I'd ask.

There are 3 tables involved in a SQL Server 2014 stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
    EntityID int,
    PrefType smallint,
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int
)

Table1
(
    EntityID int,
    PrefType smallint
)

Table2
(
    EntityID int,
    MyRowCount int
)
```

The `#TempTable` is used to process other stuff, and now contains just a few rows. I want to use those rows to `UPDATE Table2.MyRowCount` for the corresponding `EntityID` using a `COUNT(*)` from the `Table1 WHERE #TempTable.EntityID = Table1.EntityID AND #TempTable.PrefType = Table1.PrefType`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (SELECT T1.EntityID,
                   COUNT(*) T1RowCount
            FROM Table1 T1, #TempTable2 TT 
            WHERE T1.EntityID = TT.EntityID 
              AND T1.PrefType = TT.PrefType
            GROUP BY T1.EntityID) AS T1Temp ON T1Temp.EntityID = T2.EntityID 
SET T2.MyRowCount = T1Temp.T1RowCount
```

But I get a syntax error (squiggly line under T2 in "UPDATE Table2 T2" above) telling me that:

> Incorrect Syntax near 'T2'. Expecting SET.

And another squiggly line under INNER and AS with 'Incorrect Syntax' also.

Could this be a problem with using the older version of SQL Server (2014)? or is my SQL wrong/not possible?

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you'll see that for a `join` (in an update) you need a `from`, and the `set` comes before the `from`. (Pretty much as the error is telling you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DaleK already commented - have a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) when in doubt! That should be **your #1 stop** - always.

Reading the docs, you'd see you have to use this SQL statement:

```
-- UPDATE, then SET
UPDATE Table2
SET MyRowCount = T1Temp.T1RowCount
-- only then FROM and INNER JOIN
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN (SELECT T1.EntityID,
                   COUNT(*) T1RowCount
            FROM Table1 T1, #TempTable2 TT 
            WHERE T1.EntityID = TT.EntityID 
              AND T1.PrefType = TT.PrefType
            GROUP BY T1.EntityID) AS T1Temp ON T1Temp.EntityID = T2.EntityID
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK and marc_s for the solution. I actually looked at several examples (including https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/update-a-column-by-count-of-another-table) and used that as a guide, which was obviously my bad not going straight to the documentation. I'm more of a front-end guy but have to do some back-end stuff so your help is greatly appreciated. Cheers... :)